# iptables вернуть стандартные параметры

Tags: linux, сеть, iptables

Нужно было вбить команду

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 6000
```

И нечаянно вбил команду

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 6000
```

Как вернуть все на свои места? внешние устройства перестали работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iptables-save > iptables.config
nano iptables.config - тут исправляем то, что нужно
iptables-restore iptables.config
```

Answer (score 4):

> нечаянно вбил команду
>
> ```
> $ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 6000
> ```

удалите это правило, заменив опцию `-A` (add) на `-D` (delete). все остальные опции/параметры должны быть точно такими же:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 6000
```

Answer (score 0):

перезапустить службу iptables. Если конечно не было сохранения. При перезапуске службы iptables восстанавливаются первоначальные правила

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/93432)

Comment: является. Для не понимающих расшифровал

Comment: Этот ответ тянет максимум на комментарий

Comment: это ответ. Перезапуск службы зависит от системы управления оными. А что это будет systemd, upstart или sysv уже не важно. Перезапуск и все

Comment: @Doofy, для частного случая — вполне себе ответ. *maint*, но то, что это частный случай (наличие сервиса и/или старт-стопового скрипта iptables), надо бы явно оговорить в ответе. да и что такое «сохранение» — тоже неплохо бы упомянуть явно (я подозреваю, что речь о чём-то вроде пакета `iptables-persistent`, который, тоже совсем не обязательно должен присутствовать, ни в системе, ни в репозитории дистрибутива).